# SpringBoot has error during startup which caused by CLUSTER NODES returned with error

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis, redis-cluster

I used maven to build a SpringBoot project which depended on redis cluster. But I got an exception during run the compiled jar file. The exception shows that:

```
18:27:00 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.ClusterStateFailureException: Could not retrieve cluster information. CLUSTER NODES returned with error.
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
            at cn.ztuo.bitrade.UcenterApplication.main(UcenterApplication.java:23)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.ClusterStateFailureException: Could not retrieve cluster information. CLUSTER NODES returned with error.
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterConnection$JedisClusterTopologyProvider.getTopology(JedisClusterConnection.java:4241)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutor.getClusterTopology(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:349)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.ClusterCommandExecutor.executeCommandOnAllNodes(ClusterCommandExecutor.java:188)
            at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterConnection.getConfig(JedisClusterConnection.java:3263)
            at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.getNotifyOptions(ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.java:74)
            at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.configure(ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.java:55)
            at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:251)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
            ... 24 common frames omitted
```

I searched on the Google and other site and found some solutions that suggested to edit the redis.conf and set the "notify-keyspace-events" to be "Egx".

I did it. But it not worked.
I also got some other suggestions. But these suggestions do not look like fitting for the problem.
So does any one has suggestion to help me to solve the problem? Thanks.

[image: see image]

Comment: What kind of redis server are you connecting to? Local? Cloud based? provide more details on it please.

Comment: @Ameen.M local. Thanks.

Comment: I am just curious whether you are actually running a redis cluster locally? Or is it a standalone redis server?  How did you start your redis server locally? I have a strong feeling you are running redis standalone server locally. If thats the case, springboot is not able to receive the cluster information (because its not a redis-cluster)

Comment: @Ameen.M Maybe you are right that I did not start the redis server with cluster mode. I used to use the redis standalone server to run the program. But I try to edit the redis.conf to open the cluster-mode. I am not sure whether it is started with cluster-mode but it is looked like worked because that the spring-boot would show that "redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException:ERR This instance has cluster support disabled" if I did not set the cluster mode with yes. I think that I had running the redis with cluster mode. If it is not, can you told me how to run the redis cluster rightly

Comment: @Ameen.M I had set the redis.conf with that:"cluster-enabled yes\n cluster-node-timeout 15000\n clust-slave-validity-factor 10\n cluster-migration-barrier 1\n cluster-require-full-coverage yes". It is all default configuration value. I am not sure whether it means that I had running the redis cluster if I set these value and restart the redis server. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When starting the server in the logs beside the logo of redis, you should see `Running in standalone mode` or `Running in cluster mode` . If its not a cluster, I'd recommend you to google a bit to find out how to setup a cluster for your platform. https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Comment: @Ameen.M Thanks. I'll try and check whether it worked.